# Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode for Live Application (from store)

Tags: ios, xcode, pid, lldb

I am trying to attach to process by PID or Name to my application currently published on the store but without any success till now.

I need to attach the process in order to get my production push Id token since no NSLog exist. I need to retrieve that field in order to test the production push after facing issue in delivering production notification.
My Debugger shown LLDB once I clicked on "Attach to process by PID or Name"
I tried searching forums for this matter, but all I found is attaching the process in development mode.

> Could not attach to pid : “14863”
>
> Ensure “AppName” is not already running, and YourUser has permission to debug it.

Is there a way to attach apps from store and debug it?

Comment: same problem occurred with me, i think now its not possible to attach live app for debug.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @trojanfoe Message from debugger: unable to attach

Comment: What's in the logs (see *Console.app*)?

Comment: @trojanfoe Maybe this is the most helpful message that is shown in the console.app: Details:  Failed to start Instruments daemon on device “3317a23b990eed8d0a0aa3228855c88b1d340ac9”: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402653083 "Could not connect to the device." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not connect to the device., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(

Comment: That looks like an error related to an iOS device, not a failure to attach to a process under OSX.  Keep Console.app running while you attempt to connect.  Then try with the command line `lldb` and see if you get any more information.  We need to know what it's problem is.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know if the following will be useful: finder_ext[342]: requestBadgeIdentifierForURL:file:///Users/userAccount/Desktop/My%20App%20Folder/My%20App%20Store/MyApp%2011-01-2016%20v%201.0.26%20(build%201.0.27)/Year+CoreDataProperties.m
Feb 22 16:11:21 mac finder_ext[342]: sending RPC[file_sync_status /Users/userAccount/Desktop/ My App Folder/My App Store/MyApp 11-01-2016 v 1.0.26 (build 1.0.27)/Year+CoreDataProperties.m]
      <IDEExecutionOperationTracker 0x7fb794a10390 Run "MyApp" isFinished: YES>
Feb 22 16:24:11 mac finder_ext[71787]: endObservingDirectoryAtURL:file:///Users/..

Comment: That's all what I got

Comment: No I don't think that's related.

Comment: @trojanfoe Did you succeed to debug a live app before? Just to be sure first that it is doable

Comment: I haven't done it recently no.  I am not sure if there are additional debug protect applied to app store apps.  I was hoping for an error message to confirm.  Why not try with a release version of the app instead of the app store version?

Answer (score 5):

You usually can not attach the debugger to binaries built for Release.  In order for the debugger to attach to a binary, the binary has to be signed with an entitlement specifically allowing this.  That entitlement is automatically added (by Xcode) to binaries built for Debug, but not for Release.  It is technically possible to add the entitlement to a Release built binary before you code-sign it.  It is not possible to do so after the fact for obvious reasons.

I don't know whether there are store submission policies allowing this or not, however.